# VBA checking no results after filtering a table

Tags: vba, filter

I have the following table:

[image]

And the following code (that filters this table):

```
Sub testFilter()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim filteredRange As Range

    Set tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("testTbl")
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("a", "b")

    On Error Resume Next
        Set filteredRange = tbl.ListColumns("status").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If filteredRange Is Nothing Then
        'do something
    Else
        Debug.Print filteredRange.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

I expect filteredRange to be nothing.
But it's not nothing, and the address it prints is:
$1:$1,$3:$1048576
which is basically the entire sheet beside the one row I have in the table.

What am I doing wrong?
I need the ability to detect that the filter gave no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this behavior, but only if the table has only one row of data. As soon as a second row is added, it behaves as expected. I cannot find an explanation for that, could be one of the quirks of Excel.

If it can really happen with your data that the table has only one row, you could maybe use the workaround

```
If filteredRange Is Nothing Or (tbl.Range.Rows.Count = 2 And tbl.Range.Rows(2).Hidden) Then
```

One remark: I think your filter-statement needs a parameter `Operator:=xlFilterValues` if you pass an array of values:

```
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("a", "b"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. 2 questions. I tried to replace tbl.Range.Rows.Count  with tbl.databodyrange,rows,count = 1 and got an error that object doesn't wupport method. Why? second, what is the meaning of Operator:=xlFilterValues? It works (or seem to be working) without it, why do I need it?

Comment: For your first question (databodyrange): No clue, works for me. If you omit `xlFilterValues`, only one of the values of the array is used as positive filter, in your case `b`, but not `a`. This works for your example with only one row, but not if the table is larger and you really want to see all `a` and `b` rows